# Regular expression to find precise pdf links in a webpage

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

Given url='http://normanpd.normanok.gov/content/daily-activity', the website has three types of arrests, incidents, and case summaries. I was asked to use regular expressions to discover the URL strings of all the Incidents pdf documents in Python.

The pdfs are to be downloaded in a defined location.

I have gone through the link and found that Incident pdf files URLs are in the form of:

```
normanpd.normanok.gov/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-19%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf
```

I have written code :

```python
import urllib.request

url="http://normanpd.normanok.gov/content/daily-activity"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

data = response.read()      # a `bytes` object
text = data.decode('utf-8')
urls=re.findall(r'(\w|/|-/%)+\sIncident\s(%|\w)+\.pdf$',text)
```

But in the URLs list, the values are empty.
I am a beginner in python3 and regex commands. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have Incident in your regex, but not in the string. There is [this site](https://regex101.com/)  to help with python patterns,

Comment: I forgot to add  the text string that I have got has <a href="/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-19%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf">

Comment: How do you expect to find that string if you are looking for spaces when spaces are escaped with `%20`?

Comment: I am not proficient in regex in python I have written regex expression after doing some reading over internet. I thought  (%|\w)+ would cover all the those of type %20 which are in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an advisable method. Instead, use an HTML parsing library like bs4 ([BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup)) to find the links and then only regex to filter the results.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url="http://normanpd.normanok.gov/content/daily-activity"
response = urlopen(url).read()
soup= BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")     
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'(Incident%20Summary\.pdf)'))

for el in links:
    print("http://normanpd.normanok.gov" + el['href'])
```

Output :

```
http://normanpd.normanok.gov/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-23%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf
http://normanpd.normanok.gov/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-22%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf
http://normanpd.normanok.gov/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-21%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf
http://normanpd.normanok.gov/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-20%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf
http://normanpd.normanok.gov/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-19%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf
http://normanpd.normanok.gov/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-18%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf
http://normanpd.normanok.gov/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-17%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf
```

But if you were asked to use only regexes, then try something simpler:

```
import urllib.request
import re

url="http://normanpd.normanok.gov/content/daily-activity"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()      # a `bytes` object
text = data.decode('utf-8')
urls=re.findall(r'(filebrowser_download.+?Daily%20Incident.+?\.pdf)',text)
print(urls)
for link in urls:
    print("http://normanpd.normanok.gov/" + link)
```

Comment: your code works for me..I too have written a regular expression

Comment: Thanks @ettore-rizza..I too have written a regular expression s=re.findall(r'\/file[\w|\/|\-|%]+Incident[\w|%]*\.pdf',v), though not effecient has worked for me

Comment: The main thing is to find a recurring pattern. If all the files start with "filebrowser_download" and end with ".pdf", why break your head?

Answer (score 0):

Using BeautifulSoup this is an easy way:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open_page, 'html.parser')
links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    current = link.get('href')
    if current.endswith('pdf') and "Incident" in current:
        links.append('{0}{1}'.format(url,current))
```